# Macro string: what does #define __T(x) x mean? And __T(#x)?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

What does this mean?

```
#define __T(x)  x
```

Just return x?

I am seeing code using syntax I've not seen before:

```
#define CREATE_ENCODER(CODEC) \
strcpy(codecName, __T(#CODEC); \
pCodec = new CODEC##VideoEncoder();
if(parFileName) \
{  pEncoderParams = new CODEC##EncoderParams; \
}
```

What is the # for?

Answer (score 13):

Actually __T is used to turn string to wchar_t* or char*, in tchar.h you have:

```
#define __T(x)      L ## x
```

used when UNICODE is enabled and

```
#define __T(x)      x
```

when it is disabled

If your code is to be compiled on both UNICODE and non-UNICODE compilations you use:

TCHAR* sz = __T("My text");

most WINAPI functions use TCHAR* or some of its form

Actually I prefer _T() version, never knew __T version exists, at the bottom of tchar.h you have it defined:

```
#define _T(x)       __T(x)
#define _TEXT(x)    __T(x)
```

So back to your example:

```
strcpy(codecName, __T(#CODEC)); \
```

is equivalent to:

```
strcpy(codecName, "CODEC"); \
```

on NON-unicode build, and

```
strcpy(codecName, L"CODEC"); \
```

on UNICODE build

VERY IMPORTANT!!: using _T or __T is not really enough to make sure you code is UNICODE compilant. It will make it easier to call WINAPI functions. You must prepare your code to work with UNICODE.

Comment: Important note: this header (and macros) are specific to Windows because it does not use UTF-8 for Unicode.

Comment: That's not quite correct.  First, of course, `char` text is quite capable of being Unicode: think UTF-8.  And second, just changing a macro isn't going to make your code Unicode compliant; there's a lot more than simply whether the character type is 16 bits or only 8.  Things like `TCHAR` are really a type of fraud: false advertising, because they can't deliver what they promise.

Comment: Thats how you code with visual-c++ under Windows, Windows-ce (UNICODE only). There is no UTF-8, winapi functions accept either char (you must watch out for encodings), or wchar_t (2bytes UNICODE). Question has a tag visual-c++, so i suppose MS specific answer is OK. I thought it was obvious, but I added comment thet __T does not turn your app into unicode compliant code:)

Comment: Look at the code again. Original question has two underscores: __T(x), not _T(x).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that define is simply replaced with the passed value. This kind of define is often used if you e.g. want to determine at compile time if you want to pass a value through a translation function (`#define __T(x) translate(x)`) or not (`#define __T(x) x`).

`#` stringifies the passed value: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html and
`##` is the concatenation operator: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Comment: Thanks for the links.